# Xcode running iOS app without updated code. Ionic live reload not working

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

```
ionic cordova emulate ios -l <target>
```

Does not work for me. I get an error suggesting that I am targeting the wrong device even though the device I am targeting is listed as a virtual device when running the command:

```
ionic cordova emulate --list
```

When I run the app with Xcode instead it works however it does not reload my edits, even if I stop and start the app again.

*** disclaimer: this is both a quick and dirty solution to the aforementioned issues ***

**Before running your app in Xcode (pressing the play button), in your project directory run the following command:**

```
ionic cordova prepare ios
```

This will load your changes and update your app in Xcode before running it in your emulator so you can then debug and see your edits.

Open to suggestions if anyone has a more direct solution!

Answer (score -1):

Try:

1. cleaning the build folder in Xcode: cmd+shift+k
2. In the "Device" menu of Simulator, click "Erase All Content and Settings"
3. Quit Xcode, simulator and whatever program you are running the emulate command in
4. Reboot the machine